# Cannot restart explorer.exe in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

explorer.exe hanged on me and I killed it by clicking on <kbd>End Process</kbd> :

[image]

I do <kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>New Task</kbd> and started a new  `explorer.exe` process.

However, I'm currently still unable to use my taskbar and my desktop. The new `explorer.exe` is shown in the process list but it isn't working as expected.

How do we properly restart `explorer.exe` in Windows XP?

Comment: The method you are using is the proper method to restart `explorer.exe` . If you don't get your taskbar back, then it must be some other problem that prevents `explorer.exe` from starting properly. I would recommend to wait for several minutes and if it does not help - restart the machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have a "restart.bat" and type "restart" at the command-line when I want to do this.

It is, roughly:

```
@Echo off
Echo Killing explorer...
taskend /f explorer
Echo Wait 3 seconds...
sleep 3
Echo Starting explorer...
start explorer
```

This assumes you have a "sleep" command to wait 1 second, and assumes "explorer" is in your path. And of course that restart.bat is in your path too! :)

Comment: And that is exactly what my answer is, Pacerier.

Comment: I'm actually not convinced that `start explorer` would have worked because "file >> new task" is already broken. Something else seems to be the problem. I'll take this as answer for the time being until a better one comes along.

Comment: It works as long as start.exe and explorer.exe are in your path. Of course, there could be another problem.  Maybe there is a process hanging things up.  Could throw a taskend for that process into the BAT file too. It's clunky, but so is Windows :)

Comment: Do you use modern Windows like Windows 8? Or are you a Linux guy?

Comment: My solution works for any windows between Windows95 and Windows7.  I'd bet money (without any evidence) it would work under Windows8, too, assuming you've met the proper assumptions I gave.

Comment: And oh, to answer your question - Windows7 with a 64-bit 3rd party command-line (TakeCommand/TCMD/4NT/4DOS/NDOS, this thing has been around since the 1980s under different names) - with Cygwin installed so I can do all the nice unix stuff too. I tend to run cutting edge hardware, and unix variants have not once been sufficient in any of the  times I've tried it (Ultrix, FreeBSD, Slackware, RedHat, and Unbuntu).

Answer (score 3):

1. Click on `Application` tab
2. Click on `New Task` on below right hand side.
3. New window will come, there write `explorer.exe` and click on `OK`

Other way is to restart the computer.

Comment: Why doesn't one just restart the computer and/or logout of the user and just log back in.

Comment: @Ramhound You are right. But the question was how to restart the Explorer after ending the process and I think I answered that.

Comment: @Lifestohack  Yes that is the correct way, but **File → New Task** or choosing New Task from Application tab or using run, are not different from one another. You'd suggested what the author has already done and still failed to open explorer.exe. :)

Comment: @Lifestohack, This doesn't work. It does the exact same thing as `File → New Task` isn't it?

Comment: @Ramhound, There's alot of other applications running and some *working state* will be gone if I restart.

Comment: @Pacerier - Yes;  You have to be more specific other then "it doesn't work" because that's how you launch explorer.exe after manually killing explorer.exe.  You can switch to your active windows using the keyboard shortcut, save your work, and restart of course its likely something else is going on and even that won't work.

Comment: @Ramhound, I've already detailed that in the question, it doesn't work: I'm unable to use the taskbar and the desktop. Yes I can switch through all the applications and try to save off all the half-done work, but not everything can be saved. E.g. Can you save the state of 20 tabs in incognito Chrome? What about a background service running halfway?

Comment: @Pacerier - Sure;  You could simply Bookmark the pages.  If you cannot manually start explorer.exe there is **no other way** to start explorer.exe

Comment: @Ramhound, That's the point of the question in the first place. To see if anyone knows of some other way besides `File -> New Task`. Why do you think I even bother posting this question? Saving state is not that simple: What about your "forward backward" state and "scroll state" of the current tabs together with all the scroll state of all their forwards and backwards? What about halfway running background services? If restart was so easy why do people even bother inventing ["hibernation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernation_(computing)) in the first place?

Comment: @Pacerier Forget Bookmark. You can use [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko/related?hl=en) to save your current Chrome session.

Comment: @Mohi, It doesn't save forwards-backwards state or scroll states or cookie states. And I thought it was called "Session Buddy" because it was supposed to save the "session"....

Comment: @Pacerier Have your task manager started to respond? It's been an hour.

Comment: @Mohi, It's the taskbar having problem, not the task manager. Ever since I killed off explorer.exe, there's a black hole right where the taskbar should have been. If I minimize everything, the whole screen goes black.

Comment: @Pacerier Oh excuse me for that. If your task manger is up and running then why don't to you try to kill `explorer.exe` once more and start it again?

Comment: @Mohi, Yea, did that about 20 times: Doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17259/discussion-between-mohi-and-pacerier).

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to restart explorer is from any program that can run a windows program, eg taskman or cmd.exe or 4nt.

If nothing is running, then taskman.exe is indeed the correct way to start this.